# Gradle project refresh failed Error: Cannot find JAR 'kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.1.3-2.jar'

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I created a new project and getting following Gradle Sync error.

Gradle 'ProjectX' project refresh failed Error: Cannot find JAR 'kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.1.3-2.jar' required by module 'gradle-kotlin-dsl' using classpath or distribution.

I am not using 'Kotlin' and using Android 4.0(IceCreamSandwich). Below is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: If there is no specific reason to be on android 4.0, Please move to android 8.0 or 9.0 and make respective changes in build.gradle.

Comment: I will check but I think this is not a reason. I want to use android 4.0 as a minimum version. I do not know why it needs 'Kotlin' compiler.

Comment: did you resolve your issue?

Comment: yes, I think updating Android Studio and build gradle would solve this issue.